# How can Hive on Spark read data from jdbc?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

We are using Hive on Spark, and we want to do everything on hive, and using spark to calculate. That mean's we don't need to write map/reduce code but sql-like code.

And now we got a problem here, we want to read datasource like postgresql, and control it by simple sql code. And we want it run on cluster.

I've got a idea, I can write some Hive udfs to connect to a jdbc and make a table like data, but I've found it doesn't run on spark job, then it will be useless.

What we want is typing in hive like that :

```
hive>select myfunc('jdbc:***://***','root','pw','some sql here');
```

Then I can get a table in hive, and let it join others. In the other way, no matter what engine hive use, we want to read other datasource in hive.

I don't know what to do now, maybe some one can give me some advice.

---

It's there any way to do like this:

```
hive> select * from hive_table where hive_table.id in
      (select myfunc('jdbcUrl','user','pw','sql'));
```

I know that hive is used to compile the sql to MapReduce job, what I want to know is how to do to make my sql/udf compile to MapReduce job as `spark.read().jdbc(...)`

Comment: Did you configure the Hive Metastore to connect to JDBC?

Comment: The data I need doesn't come from Metastore, it comes from any datasource, i mean ,their address is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s easier to load the data from db into dataframe, then you could dump it to hive if necessary. 
Read this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

See the property name dbtable, you could load a part of a table defined in sql query.

Comment: Thank you for answer me, but we don't submit our spark job, we only submit sql to hive. That mean's we don't have permission to do with spark, but the hive.